# Why does my overflow property not work and anything that has a screen smaller than 1920px looks ugly?

Tags: css, flexbox, overflow

Everything is pretty much ready, the only issue I have is that bottom circle does not want to hide beyond body borders, even though the property is set to hidden. Could anyone take a look at the code and explain it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kumbh+Sans:wght@300;400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css" type="text/css">
  <title>Profile card component</title>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="gradient-top">
  </div>
  <div class="gradient-bottom">
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <!-- BACKGROUND THROUGH CSS -->

    <div class="personal">
      <div class="background">
        <img src="images/bg-pattern-card.svg" alt="">
      </div>
      <img  class ="victor" src="images/image-victor.jpg" alt="personal photo">
      <h1>Victor Crest <span>26</span> </h1>
      <h2>London</h2> 
    </div>



    <div class="properties">
      <div class="followers">   
        80K
       <span class="property">Followers</span> 
      </div>
      <div class="likes">
        803K
        <span class="property">Likes</span> 
      </div>
      <div class="photos">
        1.4K
        <span class="property">Photos</span> 
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

```
:root {
 font-size: 62.5%;
 font-family: "Kumbh Sans", sans-serif;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
 background-color: #19a1ae;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 min-height: 100vh;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
}

/* MAIN CARD SECTION */

.container {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 align-items: center;
 text-align: center;
 overflow: hidden;
 border-radius: 20px;
 margin-right: 2.5rem;
 margin-left: 2.5rem;
 box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1),
   -5px -5px 20px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.personal {
 background-color: #ffffff;
}

.personal .victor {
 display: inline;
 margin-top: -55px;
 border: 6px solid #ffffff;
 border-radius: 50%;
}

h1 {
 color: #2e3349;
}

h1 span {
 font-weight: 400;
 color: #6b7082;
}

h2 {
 font-size: 1.4rem;
 font-weight: 400;
 color: #6b7082;
 padding-bottom: 1em;
}

/* STAT SECTION  */

.properties {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-around;
 align-items: center;
 padding: 1.3em 1em;
 background-color: #ffffff;
 width: 100%;
 font-size: 1.8rem;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #2e3349;
 border-top: 1px solid #e8e9ec;
}

.property {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 color: #6b7082;
 font-weight: 400;
 font-size: 1rem;
 letter-spacing: 0.15em;
 padding-top: 0.8em;
}
/* CIRCLES */

.gradient-top {
 z-index: -10;
 position: absolute;
 background-image: url("images/bg-pattern-top.svg");
 background-size: contain;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 top: -35%;
 left: -31.5%;
}

.gradient-bottom {
 z-index: -10;
 position: absolute;
 background-image: url("images/bg-pattern-bottom.svg");
 background-size: contain;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 bottom: -50%;
 right: -31%;
}

}
/* the bottom one causes the problem fsr*/
```

Repo link: https://github.com/ViyanMd/personal-card
Pages link: https://viyanmd.github.io/personal-card/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! When writing a question, please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) within your question without linking to an external source. Also, to further focus your question, please include what you have already tried. For more help, see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hi, a reproducible example is a snippet of complete code which we can run and demonstrates the problem. Please include enough HTML to demo the problem and any other relevant CSS.

Answer (score -1):

The issue was fixed by wrapping the whole content in another div, applying to it properties, that were applied to body before. For some reason the child element started to behave differently and the issue was solved.